# fetching a text val in form of integer from firefox for (instagram bot) project

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, firefox, instagram

i am trying to make a bot using selenium

so far i have made a login function which logs me into my account and takes me to my profile

```
class insta_logger():
    '''
    sets the driver and opens up the chrome;;;
    then it takes the username and password from the user and helps him log in 
    using the logger function
    '''
    
    def __init__(self,username,password):
        self.browser = webdriver.Firefox()
        self.username=username
        self.password=password
        
    def login_in_func(self):

        self.browser.get("https://instagram.com")
        sleep(2)

        driver.fullscreen_window()

        login_key=self.browser.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@name="username"]')
        login_pass=self.browser.find_elements_by_css_selector('form input')[1]
        login_key.send_keys(self.username)
        login_pass.send_keys(self.password)
        login_pass.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
        sleep(6)
```

this totally works fine

but what i want is that it should go to a particular insta_id and take the no of posts there are and like them one by one

so i wrote this liker function on my own

just to test whether it is able to take on the no or not,
I tried to test it first
so that it can print out the no's atleast..

```
        
    def liker(self,username):
        sleep(3)
        self.browser.get("https://instagram.com/"+username+'/')
        posts=self.browser.find_element_by_class_name('g47SY')
        #this class name changes if full screen is not present 
         #so take care of that
        if posts :
            try:
                for post in int(posts):
                    print(post)
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
            finally:
                sleep(3)
```

but it gave me a weird error

```
int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'FirefoxWebElement'
```

any help about how can i take the no of posts as int will help

[this explains better of what int I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P87gz.png)

---

Answer (score 2):

`posts` is an Element, something like: `<span class="g47SY ">3</span>`.

You want the text inside of it, so you should do `for post in range(int(posts.text))`.

For the class that changes if the browser is on fullscreen or not, you can write a function to check if an element is present or not by using a try/except block:

```
def class_present(self, class_name):
    try:
        element = self.browser.find_element_by_class_name(class_name)
        return element
    except:
        return False
```

And then:

```
xpath_full   = '//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/div/header/section/ul/li[1]/span/span'
xpath_mobile = '//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/div/ul/li[1]/span/span'

posts = self.browser.find_element_by_xpath(xpath_full) if class_present('g47SY') else self.browser.find_element_by_class_name(xpath_mobile)
```

Comment: i am not sure about it but how can you use `self.browser` without passing `self`  as a parameter along with `class_name ` . again i am not sure if we can do that ,,so please clear this doubt tooo

Comment: also it will be nice if you can help me with `posts syntax` since `?` gives a syntax error

Comment: well after some modifications it got solved thanks for the help again

Comment: @shyam_gupta Haha sorry, don't know what's wrong with me today

Comment: no problem !!.you almost guided me all the way thanks again